# I tried to create a react app but it is givinig me errors when I had the node version 9.7.2 and npm version 6.4.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ubuntu-16.04

Creating a new React app in /home/sunidhi/Documents/major.

> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
>   react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
>
> yarn add v1.7.0 [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching packages...
>   error eslint@5.6.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this
>   module. Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0". error Found
>   incompatible module info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for
>   documentation about this command.
>
> Aborting installation.   yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom
>   react-scripts --cwd /home/sunidhi/Documents/major has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting generated file...
>   yarn.lock Deleting major/ from /home/sunidhi/Documents Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best route is using nvm (node version manager) to install node.

1. Follow the instructions on web to install nvm.
2. Install node using nvm.
3. Install npm.
4. Then worry about React and install it via npm.

[install nvm](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/)

Comment: Just to document, I had to work this solution to resolve this jode.js issue after upgrading MacOS to Mojave 10.14.1, followed this simple steps with the tutorial link provided and everything worked perfect!